# React Native - Drawer Navigation Gesture Start point

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I'm using React native drawer navigation, when you swipe out from the left or right - it opens the drawer.

Does anyone know a way of changing the gesture start point, so that it starts slightly further into the screen?

My users are finding on curved screens it doesn't always drag out and feels un-natural to use.

I've looked through the documentation and couldn't find anything there.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `edgeWidth` props in react-navigation drawer.

edgeWidth-
Allows for defining how far from the edge of the content view the swipe gesture should activate.

For more details https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator/#edgewidth

Comment: How did i miss that?! Thank you!